# Why OnLoad() called twice when But predefined Load event executes once When Do RightToLeft?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtraeditors

Something very strange when i search in **community**. people always said override `OnLoad()` method because it created Handles and so on. not Predefined event `Load`

But When doing RightToLeft the `OnLoad()` called twice unlike `Load` event which called only once.

**Edited**

***DmitryG*** explains it well in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to: Enable RTL Mode in a Right-to-Left Culture Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115827/Build-an-Application/Right-to-Left-Layout/How-to-Enable-RTL-Mode-in-a-Right-to-Left-Culture-Application):

> At runtime, avoid changing the RightToLeft or RightToLeftLayout property at runtime for **forms that are already displayed**.

Generally, the Right-to-Left layout is not just `flipping a screen` but this is a massive change that affects the layout of the controls, their texts, images, and other cultural-specific properties and even more. So the **handle recreation** and then control's reloading **may be an expected behavior** in this situation.

Anyway, I suggest you [contact the DevExpress Support Team](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) in this regard.

PS. The most appropriate way to change the Right-to-Left mode in this situation is **restarting your application** with updated cultural settings. Take a look at the [Application.Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.restart?view=netframework-4.8) as a possible way to accomplish this task.

[How to: Enable RTL Mode for Form's Controls, Strings and Images in a Multiple Culture Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115871/Build-an-Application/Right-to-Left-Layout/How-to-Enable-RTL-Mode-for-Form-s-Controls-Strings-and-Images-in-a-Multiple-Culture-Application)

Answer (score 0):

you may try using onrendered(), it is called only once and when the form is completely loaded.

Comment: Where this method you got? i mean WinForms

Comment: in the .xaml file, its like this 

ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"